# How do I produce ActionResult from a DataContract-attributed class instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, datacontract, actionresult

In my MVC3 application I need to return an XML representation of a class that has `DataContract` attribute on it. MVC3 actions return `ActionResult`s.

```
[HttpGet]
ActionResult MyActionResult( paramsHere )
{
    if(!ValidateParams(paramsHere)) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    var myDataContractAttributedObject = getObject();
    return ... // how do I convert my [DataContract]-attributed object to ActionResult?
}
```

I guess I can use `DataContractSerializer` explicitly but isn't there maybe some automatic MVC magic for doing this?

How do I get `ActionResult` from my `[DataContract]`-attributed object?